# sqlite how to optimize query for Nth percentile

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, query-optimization

Here is a piece of code that uses `sqlite3` [python module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) to fetch the Nth percentile `value` for item with id `itemid` from table `history`.

```
def getNthPercentile(cursor, itemId, N=99.9):
    # get 99.9 percentile
    # find count of values
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(value) FROM history WHERE itemid=?", [itemId])
    cnt = int(cursor.fetchone()[0])
    # offset gives us teh position of the value in sorted list that represents Nth percentile
    offset = int(cnt * (N / 100) - 1)
    # sort values
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM history WHERE itemid = ? ORDER BY value ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?", [itemId, offset])
    percentile = float(cursor.fetchone()[0]);
    l.debug('itemId=%d, count=%d, offset=%d, %fth percentile=%f' % (itemId, cnt, offset, N, percentile))
    # find the (count * pctlVal)th item in sorted values
    return percentile

cursor = getDbCursor()
for itemId in listOfItemIds:
    print 'Nth percentile for %d is %f' % (itemId, getNthPercentile(cursor, itemId))
```

Questions are:

- Is it possible to do this in a single query?
- Is it possible to do this for a list of itemIds (instead of one at a time) in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in a single query.
Use cursor.executescript to call those two statements in one execution and store cnt as a temporary variable in sqlite.

```
cursor.executescript("SELECT COUNT(value) AS itemcount FROM history WHERE itemid=?; \
    SELECT value FROM history WHERE itemid = ? ORDER BY value ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET itemcount * (? / 100) - 1)", \
    [itemId, itemId, percentile])
```

^^ I haven't tested this at all, but it should be close.

I have no idea if some form of executescript combined with executemany is possible. So you might have to decide between two executemanys or executescripts for each itemid.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It does, in a way, answer my question. Not what I hoped for but...